# firefox addon: how to debug simple-storage using addon builder

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using the online Firefox Addon Builder (https://builder.addons.mozilla.org) to develop my addon, and I'm having some problems with the simple-storage. For the code bellow, I get the same information on the console, for every time I run it (using the "test" option on the addon builder), ie, the value doesn't seem to be stored:

```
var ss = require("sdk/simple-storage");

console.log("BEFORE INIT");
console.log(JSON.stringify(ss.storage));

if (!ss.storage.pages)
    ss.storage.pages = [];

console.log("AFTER INIT");
console.log(JSON.stringify(ss.storage));
```

console:

```
[14:32:38.892] info: xxx: BEFORE INIT
[14:32:38.893] info: xxx: {}
[14:32:38.893] info: xxx: AFTER INIT
[14:32:38.893] info: xxx: {"pages":[]}
```

I assume this happens because the addon builder creates a new test package every time I run the test, and the storage is private to the addon (and apparently to every test package within the same addon):

```
[14:31:36.165] "installing from /xpi/test/2d6e6appf76kg/"
...
[14:32:36.378] "installing from /xpi/test/2d6e6appf7r40/"
```

I tried restarting firefox and then it seems to work (shows me the right thing on the console). How to debug my code without constantly having to restart firefox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root of this is a mixture of intended behavior of the SDK and the way the builder-addon operates.

- The SDK will actually [purge](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/a44176661b1b61dffb46ce2ff5a4156bda38cf49/lib/sdk/simple-storage.js#L130) the storage upon uninstall. This behavior is intended but [broken](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627432) when using the regular UI to uninstall add-ons.
- The builder (actually the helper add-on) will always uninstall the old version and reinstall a new version and wipe out the simple-storage by doing so.

There are several work-arounds that let you keep the simple-storage data

- Don't use the builder, but the plain SDK with the `--profiledir=PROFILEDIR`
- Always disable the add-on before updating it ((ab)uses the broken behavior mentioned above).
- **Don't use the `simple-storage` module at all.** Like LocalStorage it is synchronous by nature doing synchronous I/O on the main thread, which really hurts performance. If you only have a few, short values, use the preferences, e.g. via the `simple-prefs` module instead. If you have much data, preferably use something like [`OS.File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread). If you need something relational, then consider using [`indexed-db`](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/indexed-db.html) or [`SQLite.jsm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Sqlite.jsm). For `OS.File` and/or `SQLite.jsm`, you'll need [chrome access](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/chrome.html).